# Having node version 8.11.2 and cli version 7.1.2 but showing "You are running version v8.11.2 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+."

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface

I was getting some version error from the start of my project so after this I uninstalled and deleted all files of node and cli and installed from the beginning. And now when I am running npm start it is showing:

You are running version v8.11.2 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.

Where my version details are:
[image]

Updated: 
When using node 10.16.0 showing this error
[image]

I have tried installing packages again and again after deleting it but it hasn't worked. I have removed all the packages and installed again but it didn't work.

Comment: It should be quite clear from the error and ng v output. You're running nodejs 8.11.2, the CLI wants 10.9 or greater. Update [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your machine.

Comment: Have you tried installing Node.js 10.9 or greater from https://nodejs.org/en/?

Comment: nodejs != angular. These versions do not relate to one another, except that one might require the other to be at a minimum, so update nodejs.

Comment: I have added updates to my question showing whar happens when I use node version 10.16.0

Comment: If you read your second error it says `npm` does not support node v10.16.0. So update `npm` which is not the same as `node`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that `NPM` and `NodeJS` versions on your machine should meet Angular v8's expectations.

So ***make sure your NPM is updated to support Node.js version(10.16.0)***.

As per your error screenshot:

It turns out that the current installed `npm` is not compatible with the new `node` and has a hard time updating.

The solution is to uninstall `npm`, clear `npm cache` and then reinstall node which will contain the correct version of `npm`.